# Java JFrame set not to resize, resizes anyways

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe

I have a JFrame maximized using

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Some code between that and at the end

```
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setResizeable(false);
```

Tough, Dragging the top of the window down resizes it anyways.
I added a ComponentListener to it to see if it detects being resized, and it does. The componentResized function gets called when i do the resize.
Any fix for this?
Thanks.

Comment: It is best if you post your codes.

Comment: please post your code, the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be the best

Comment: I know it's just a temporary (and not great) fix, but if you know the ComponentListener is called on componentResized you can store the original width and height and on componentResized change it back. Or, you know, post your code so we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Dragging the top of the window down resizes it anyways

This is the way applications work in Windows. Try a native Windows application and you will see the dragging the window causes it to shrink to a preferred size.

You could try code like the following:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.pack();
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getSize());
```

You can still drag the frame from its position, but you will not be able to resize it.

Comment: but it doesn't work like that in my code...with setting like in OP example, I can drag window and it don't change size, and I cannot change size.